# Recurrence relation with a period of 4

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, recurrence-relations

$u_{1}=\alpha$ and $u_{n+1}=\frac{1+u_n}{1-u_n}$. Prove that $n=5$ gives the first value of $n$ for which $u_{n}=\alpha$ and that this is so for all but three values of $\alpha$

So I have shown that $u_2=\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}$,$u_3=-\frac{1}{\alpha}$,$u_4=\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}$ and finally $u_5=\alpha$ and we need $\alpha\ne0,-1,1$.

I know I am also supposed to check that $u_2,u_3,u_4$ can never be $\alpha$.

But the suggested answer says "...need to consider cases where a term prior to $u_5$ could be equal to $u_1$ and this requires scrutiny of both $u_2$ and $u_3$ but not $u_4$..."

I don't understand why "...but not $u_4$..."? Is there a need to check if $u_4$ can be $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2):

If $u_4=u_1$ then $u_5=u_2$, $u_6=u_3$ etc, so that the sequence repeats with period
$3$ as well as period $4$.
But in this case $u_4=u_1$ and we know $u_5=u_1$ also. As $u_5=u_2$ then
$u_2=u_1$
and you have ruled out this case.

Comment: That explains! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check periodicy also like this. Define $\alpha _n = \arctan(u_n)$ then we have $$\tan (\alpha _{n+1}) = {\tan {\pi \over 4} + \tan (\alpha _n)\over 1- \tan {\pi \over 4}\tan (\alpha _n) } = \tan ({\pi \over 4} + \alpha _n)$$  so $$u_{n+4}  =\tan (\alpha _{n+4}) =\tan (\pi+ \alpha _{n}) = u_n$$ and we are done.

Comment: This also shows that none of the intermediate values are equal. It also suggests looking at $a_{n+1} = \tan(a_n+\pi/m)$ for integer m to create a recurrence in disguise. Use, for example, $\tan(\pi/3) = \sqrt{3}$ or, according to Wolfy, $\tan(\pi/5) = \sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sqrt{15} = \sqrt{23 - 10 \sqrt{5} - 2 \sqrt{3 (85 - 38 \sqrt{5})}}$.